# Wireguard client connected to internet but unable to ping client from server

Tags: networking, server, vpn, wireguard

I have a Wireguard server with two clients (mobile and a laptop) connected to the server. I want to be able to route my traffic on specific ports on my wireguard server to the laptop.
Configuration for the server and clients is given below. 
Server:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.66.66.1/24,fd42:42:42::1/64
ListenPort = 57777
PrivateKey = <redacted>
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

### Client wg-mobile
[Peer]
PublicKey = <redacted>
PresharedKey = <redacted>
AllowedIPs = 10.66.66.3/32,fd42:42:42::3/128

### Client laptop
[Peer]
PublicKey = <redacted>
PresharedKey = <redacted>
AllowedIPs = 10.66.66.4/32,fd42:42:42::4/128
```

Client wg-mobile

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <redacted>
Address = 10.66.66.3/32,fd42:42:42::3/128
DNS = 176.103.130.130,176.103.130.131

[Peer]
PublicKey = <redacted>
PresharedKey = <redacted>
Endpoint = vpn-domain.tld:57777
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0,::/0
```

Client laptop

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <redacted>
Address = 10.66.66.4/32,fd42:42:42::4/128
DNS = 176.103.130.130,176.103.130.131

[Peer]
PublicKey = <redacted>
PresharedKey = <redacted>
Endpoint = vpn-domain.tld:57777
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0,::/0
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

The two clients are connected in the wireguard network as 10.66.66.3/32 (android) and 10.66.66.4/32 (ubuntu 20.04 laptop).
Both the clients are connected to the wireguard vpn and able to access the internet.
However, when I ping the 2nd client from,  `ping 10.66.66.4`, it is stuck but when I try to ping the first client `ping 10.66.66.3` from server, ping works fine.

I have tried using the mobile client's configuration on my laptop, again it is connected to the vpn but now `ping 10.66.66.3` on the server is stuck. So I am guessing this is an issue on laptop.

I am not sure if it is a firewall issue on my laptop or something else. I want to be able to route my traffic on specific ports on my wireguard server to the laptop. Currently, I am able to route traffic on port 80 on wireguard server to the mobile client using proxy_pass in nginx as `proxy_pass 10.66.66.3`
I want to be able to do this for laptop also. Can someone guide me in the right direction. I am unable to figure out what I am missing here.

Comment: This is a subnetting issue. Try changing 10.66.66.3/32 and 10.66.66.4/32 to 10.66.66.3/24 and 10.66.66.4/24 then see if the ping echoes.

Comment: Can you explain how would that help? I did that but still having the same issue. I am able to ping mobile ip from server but not laptop client ip.

Comment: Unless some sort of routing is involved, `10.66.66.4/32` can only see itself https://www.adminsub.net/ipv4-subnet-calculator/10.66.66.4/32 . However upon reading your post again, it seems there is routing since the client can access internet and connectivity is fine. I wold check if for example a firewall is up on the client first and not bother with the server since switching the clients IPs made no difference.